# use targetSdkVersion29, Unable to discover BLE Device

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

When targetsdkversion is set to 28, ble devices can be searched normally.

But I can't find ble devices when targetsdkversion is set to 29.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" android:required="false"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="andriod.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" android:required="false"/>
```

My code is as follows

```
bluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner().startScan(buildScanFilters(), buildScanSettings(), new ScanCallback() {
@Override
public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
    super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);
    
}

@Override
public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
    super.onBatchScanResults(results);
}

@Override
public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
    super.onScanFailed(errorCode);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for runtime permissions as well? Specifically for Fine Location?

From https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#location-telephony-bluetooth-wifi:

> Note: If your app runs on Android 10 or higher but targets Android 9
> (API level 28) or lower, you can use the affected APIs (except for
> WifiP2pManager APIs) as long as your app has declared either the
> ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.

This might be the case you're running into, as previously, only having Coarse Location alone was okay.

Also, not sure if it's just a copy/paste error - but in your code, there is a typo in the `<uses-permission android:name="andriod.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" android:required="false"/>` line --> "andriod".

Alternatively, maybe try out the Companion Device API?

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/companion-device-pairing